# Anchors in links

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-routing

Given:

- Tom — who has a modern browser which is pushState-enabled
- Fred — who has a browser which is not pushState-enabled
- a `super.app` web application powered by Backbone

Tom browses to `products/1` page where a `#special-offer` section exists.

Does Backbone allow Tom to share a link with Fred including the anchor to the special-offer section: http://super.app/products/1#special-offer

Will Fred be redirected to http://super.app/#products/1 (eg: without the `#special-offer`)?

In other words, does Backbone allow to use anchors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a test here http://bl.ocks.org/abernier/raw/3183257/

It appears that YES:

- anchors can be used with pushState-enabled browsers : `http://bl.ocks.org/abernier/raw/3183257/product1.html#special-offer`
- while for IE<10, it is converted to `http://bl.ocks.org/abernier/raw/3183257/#product1.html` eg: without `#special-offer`

The only thing I had to take care about was to disable anchors for hashes-based history browsers, by:

```
if (!Backbone.history._hasPushState) {
  $('body').delegate('a[href^=#]', 'click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Backbone has a very customizable use of *hash URL fragments* within its modules [Router](http://backbonejs.org/#Router) and [History](http://backbonejs.org/#History).

Comment: Funny thing is there are anchors in your links :) but unfortunately, Backbone's documentation you're referring here doesn't deal with anchors. So it leaves my question unanswered...

Comment: I have been using _hash-based URL fragments_ in old Backbone projects, so I think it supports it, maybe I'm understanding wrong your _URL anchor_ description but I think I don't. The documentation in my links is almost hiding the comments about _hash-based URL fragments_ because it is adding more importance to the use of [HTML5 history API](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html), but you can read _"Until recently, hash fragments (#page) were used to provide these permalinks..."_ and _"...the Router handles graceful fallback and transparent translation to the fragment version of the URL"_